# View items using a term and include it's children

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, term, term-set

Is it possible for me to create a view that when I enter a term and the result is a list of all items with that term associated with it but also have it return the children of the entered term as well.

Example
Terms:

- Microsoft

  - Office
  - Outlook

So if we were so say that the term we search for is Microsoft, it will filter for that term and it's children.

Currently we are using a URL filter so that when you arrive at the page it will filter Microsoft but we cannot see a way for it to automatically filter for the terms Children as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How we ended up solving this issue, was to use `FilterName=<name>&FilterMultiValue=<value>*`
Using the wildcard '*' on the end allows us to have all the sub terms appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#` before the term ID as it means query for the specified term ID or the ID of any of that term’s child terms, e.g., `owstaxidGeography:#52263385-1fc3-4323-8d6b-50c8f6c3c45d`.

Comment: hy, thats interesting. do you have any further information for me about this? is there anything official?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx